# `Do` structures - listing iterated values

Tags: programming

Please excuse the crudity / simplicity of this question, hbut I have never really got on too well with `Do` structures - perhaps I don't use them enough - perhaps I avoid them!

How would I create a do loop that performs a given operation on each new value?

eg

```
val=10;
Log@val // N
a = 39 - %
b = % - Log@%
c = % - Log@%
d = % - Log@%
e = % - Log@%
ToExpression[CharacterRange["a", "e"]]
```

Of course it can be done with

```
f[0] = 10;
f[1] = N[f[0] - Log@f[0]]
f[n_] := f[n - 1] - Log[f[n - 1]]

f[5]
```

but I was wondering whether `Do` could do the operation.

Comment: Is the main goal to do this with a `Do` loop, or to execute this list of operations? In general, this looks a lot like a `FoldList` kind of construct.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP yes, would really like to do it with `Do`

Comment: Judging by the edit, you might as well `f[0]=10.; Do[f[i]=f[i-1]-Log[f[i-1]],{i,n}]`

Comment: `(tmp = 10; Do[tmp = N[tmp - Log[tmp]], {#}]; tmp) &`...

Comment: @ciao looks good, but can't get it to work ... sorry, I really am not good with these `Do` structures

Comment: @martin: Sorry for tardy reply - that's just an example (and why it's not an answer post) of the latter result, or more properly a 'Do' version of a `Nest` - so `(tmp = 10; Do[tmp = N[tmp - Log[tmp]], {#}]; tmp) &@5` is final result equiv. to `f[5]`... substitute some n for 5 for same as `f[n]`. N.b. - it is only final result, re-reading your OP I think you want intermediates assigned also, so *Bob*'s answer covers it nicely (+1 on him)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As shown by @LLIAMnYP

```
Clear[f]

f[0] = 10.; Do[f[i] = f[i - 1] - Log[f[i - 1]], {i, 10}]
```

The calculated function values are

```
f /@ Range[0, 10]
```

> ```
> {10., 7.69741, 5.65653, 3.92372, 2.55668, 1.61797, 1.1368, 1.00858,
> 1.00004, 1., 1.}
> ```

This sequence can also be generated with `NestList`

```
NestList[# - Log[#] &, 10., 10]
```

> ```
> {10., 7.69741, 5.65653, 3.92372, 2.55668, 1.61797, 1.1368, 1.00858,
> 1.00004, 1., 1.}
> ```

This sequence converges to `1.` with any positive initial value

```
FixedPoint[# - Log[#] &, .000001]
```

> ```
> 1.
> ```

```
FixedPoint[# - Log[#] &, 1000000.]
```

> ```
> 1.
> ```

However, the number of terms required for convergence to the fixed point can vary radically

```
FixedPointList[# - Log[#] &, .000001] // Length
```

> ```
> 15
> ```

```
FixedPointList[# - Log[#] &, 1000000.] // Length
```

> ```
> 78633
> ```

Comment: superfast! This is great - and thanks for helping with my `Do` loop education ;)